# Laravel routing & database MySQL different output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am studying Laravel Framework for few hours and i am trying to do what's being done in the tutorial i am watching. I am executing a query through routes.php and it's giving me a different output.

My database has only 1 table and it is named 'customer' and i have a model named 'customer' and a controller named 'CustomerController'

My routes.php code is this

```
Route::get('customer', function() {
$customer = FirstLaravelApplication\Customer::find(1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($customer);
```

But the localhost is giving me an error and it says i don't have any 'customers' table, it automatically added a letter 's' in the end of the table instead of 'customer' only. i really don't have any 'customers' table i don't know why it is passing the wrong name of the table but my code only says 'customer'.

i would appreciate any help! Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel/Eloquent ORM uses this convention, as do many ORMs.  They pluralize table names.

Open up the Customer.php model and add in:

```
class Customer extends Model {

    // Add this
    protected $table = 'customer';
```

However, it's usually easier to stick with the framework's conventions.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: OMG!!! It worked! Thank you very much you saved my day! But one more question? Do i have to do that on every table that i will have since if it pluralizes a table it can also to the others? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you didn't pluralize your other tables, then yes, for every model you'll need to adjust this.  If I wanted to break a convention like this for every model, I would extend the Model class and remove the pluralize logic.  It all depends on what you feel comfortable with.  I think you'll find it would be easier for you to stick with keeping tables pluralized if you want to use Laravel.

Comment: Okay i get it so i'll just need to create a 'function' like that make it protected. Thank you very much again! Last question. I'm sorry you are so great i can't stop asking XD Was it my doing that made it pluralize or the Framework does it on every table?

Comment: Well, Laravel framework uses the Eloquent ORM.  It is the default in Eloquent to have tables pluralized.  Check out the link I added for the conventions.  Learning the conventions of the framework is as important as the code.